# Unclear step when proving linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

I don't understand how we choose the x-values to solve the equation system proving linear independence. For example I have this question:

[image]

Proving the linear dependence is trivial, but then this follows:

[image]

So I underand the first part, but how do we choose the three x values, namely x = 0, x = -1 and x = 1?

Comment: We can chose any three different values for $x$.

Comment: So why do we sometimes choose 2 or other values? (at least in my exercises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose arbitrary values for $x$. It's purely for simplification purposes. In this case choosing $x=0$ in $\alpha_1+\alpha_2\cdot 0+\alpha_2 \cdot (1+0+0^2) = 0$ simplifies to $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=0$. The values are usually chosen as a solution to one of the polynomials. In this case $x$ and $x^2+x+1$. The second polynomial doesn't have real solutions so you can't pick a nice number there instead they use $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: Okay, so even for a different exercise, here we could also have chosen -3, 5 and 8? https://imgur.com/a/l15TkgH

Comment: As long as it's within the domain of these functions then yes.

Comment: Thank you a lot